# Can I define generic Beans in Spring?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, generics

Can I make a generic class that requires the type of its generic parameter `Class<T>` as constructor argument available as `@Bean` in Spring?

Generic class:

```
public class Repository<T> {

    public Repository(Class<T> type) {
        //...
    }
}
```

My current `@Bean` definitions:

```
@Bean
public Repository<Car> carRepository() { return new Repository<>(Car.class) }

@Bean
public Repository<Garage> carRepository() { return new Repository<>(Garage.class) }

//... one for each type I require
```

What I would like:

```
@Bean
public <T> Repository<T> genericRepository() { return new Repository<>(T.class) }
```

I've already looked into Spring's [`ResolvableType`](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/core/ResolvableType.html), but it doesn't seem like that's what I'm looking for. Is there a way to get a hold of `T`'s class without requiring a constructor argument? Does spring offer a mechanism for it?

Comment: No, you can't. You see to be reinventing Spring-data. Why not just learn and use it instead?

Comment: @JBNizet Could you point me to relevant docs that would solve this problem?

Comment: There isn't any. I answered "No, you can't". But spring-data would wllow you to avoid defining all these repositories in the first place. https://spring.io/projects/spring-data

Comment: @JBNizet Actually I'm implementing my own [Axon](https://axoniq.io) repository. They have a [`GenericJpaRepository<T>`](https://axoniq.io/apidocs/3.3/org/axonframework/commandhandling/model/GenericJpaRepository.html) that is automatically instantiated for each `@Aggregate` annotated class. I wonder how it's done.